# Remove quantity box for specific product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, quantity

I installed Magento 1.9.2.1 and I need to delete the box quantity only on some products.

I was thinking, for example, when max quantity is set to 1, instead of for other products leave the box.

Thank you, do you have any suggestions?

File **addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('core/nbproductdesign')->showButtonDesign(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with this file below:

```
app/design/frontend/[yourPackage]/[yourTheme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Insert the code `$_product->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() == 1` condition around qty box:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <!--START THE CONDITION -->
    <?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() > 1): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    <!--END THE CONDITION-->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Yes! The condition could be added to the first `if`:

```
if(!$_product->isGrouped() && $_product->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() > 1)
```

Comment: Perfect works, you can also choose the value> or ==. Thank you

Comment: If it has helped you then you should accept the answer.

Comment: I agree with Adarsh Khatri :)